# Install imagemagick on windows with xampp

Tags: windows, xampp, imagemagick

I really need to get imagemagick working on my windows xampp installation, I havent been able to find any good tutorials on how to do it though, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally your web script needs to know wher to find the ImageMagick executables. You can try just adding that path to the PATH environment variable for the user running Apache. Better yet, and this is more common, the web app will normally have some form of config file which needs to have the path to the executables entered in.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming you have this part done:**

1)  Download and install XAMPP

2)  Download and install ImageMagick.

---

**Confirm its working:**

1)  Start XAMPP

2)  Run this code in your browser to prove ImageMagick is installed (and working).

> ```
> <?php 
> header("Content-Type: text/plain"); 
> system("convert -version"); 
> ?>
> ```

3)  If the above works then you should be able to run code like this (in your browser):

> ```
> <?php
> exec("convert infile.jpg -thumbnail 100x100 outfile.jpg");
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Does XAMPP come with ActiveState Perl or Strawberry Perl or some other??

XAMPP may not come with ImageMagick installed by default, which is highly likely, I would just run the Perl updater tool for XAMPP to get the ImageMagick package and compile it into your environment.  I don't know much about XAMPP and so this advice only gives you a little milage on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

***ImageMagick 6.9.2-3 Q16 x86 Install on 

xampp win32 5.6.12-0-VC11 on a 

64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate System***

32-bit xampp was installed at c:/xampp--its install warning NOT to install it in a Program Files directory was a bit cryptic, as if written by a non-native English speaker.

xampp expects imagemagick to be installed at *its* root, which is at c:/xampp/htdocs/xampp, not at Window's root, /.

I installed the 32-bit ImageMagick directory at that location, then ran the two tests suggested by KPWINC. Use them.

I installed both 32-bit packages of xampp and ImageMagick on my 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate system, hearing too many problems brought on by the 64-bit versions.

Dr D0UG